# Given that the tangent to the curve $y=3(x+2)(x-2)$ at the point A is perpendicular to the line $6y+x=3$, find the coordinates of $A$

Tags: calculus

Given that the tangent to the curve $y=3(x+2)(x-2)$ at the point A is perpendicular to the line $6y+x=3$, find the coordinates of $A$

Since $y=3(x+2)(x-2)$ is the normal to the tangent $6y+x=3$ ,

I made $y1=y2$

$3(x^2-4) = -1/6 x + 1/2 $

However , I don't get the answer I need.

But , when I did

Slope Tangent X slope Normal = $-1$

I found that $x = -1 $ .

What's the difference ? Why I couldn't get $x=-1$ with the first method ?

Comment: You are looking for a point on a line which is perpendicular to the line specified.  So the slope of the unknown line will be...  note that the specified line is not tangent to the curve at the point $A$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Slope of line $6y+x=3$ is $-1/6$
2. Any line perpendicular to that line has slope $+6$
3. The given curve can be written $y= 3x^2-12$
4. The tangent to that curve over a given $x=x_0$ has slope $dy/dx|_{x_0} = 6x_0$
5. So you want to find $x_0$ such that $6x_0 = 6$